# Reverse tunnel, remote desktop session hangs when moving PuTTY window

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, putty, reverse-tunnel

I have a ssh server on my Windows 10 computer at home and when I set up a reverse tunnel from my Windows 10 work computer with PuTTY with this command:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@xxxxxxxxxx -R 9999:localhost:3389
```

I can use remote desktop at home and log into my work computer.

This works until I move the PuTTY window, then my local window freezes. The workaround is to do not touch that window, but that is very annoying.
Is this a known problem?

To make it clear: only the window on my home computer in which I'm viewing my work computer (the remote desktop window) freezes. Everything else on my home computer works fine and when I ask my colleague who is at work to look at my work computer he says that he can see the PuTTY window with a message that the connection is lost. He is able to close PuTTY and reconnect to my home computer with the above command and everything works again until I accidentally click the PuTTY window again.

Comment: Which version of putty do you use?

Comment: Only the window on my home computer in which I'm viewing my work computer (the remote desktop window) freezes. Everything else on my home computer works fine and when I ask my colleague who is at work to look at my work computer he says that he can see the putty window with a message that the connection is lost. He is able to close putty and reconnect to my home computer with the above command and everything works again until I accidentally click the putty window again.

Comment: I have this same issue. To work around it, I connect and then minimize PuTTY. I still occasionally manage to restore the PuTTY window while in remote desktop which promptly freezes the session. If you just need the tunnel, maybe try `plink.exe` instead of a full PuTTY session.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks for the plink tip; works like a charm! If you'd post it as an answer, you'd have my vote as the answer.

Comment: Same issue with [KiTTY](https://github.com/cyd01/KiTTY).  klink.exe workaround works there too.

Comment: @Ouroborus don't know what possessed you to try plink but it did the job for me. not much info about this on the net.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is manifested when the putty application is launched from the user's session, which is then connected via RDP. The problem can be bypassed if to launch putty from another user's session or to create a job that will launch putty under NETWORK SERVCE user.
[examble of job four launch putty from system account to permit connection to RDP trough ssh tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpOWh.png)